# Is there any way of finding, which SQL Server user has changed other SQL Server user permissions in SQL Server 2014 Enterprise?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, a user had changed by sysadmin access to public one. Is there any way of finding out *which* user had changed my permissions on my instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use default trace to find add role member event [Using the SQL Server Default Trace to Audit Events](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3445/using-the-sql-server-default-trace-to-audit-events/)